# successfully reverse the transition with js ,but why my another way doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

- my demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beetcb/r12tLx0z/26/)
- What I want is a **reverse transition** when I click the < li > again, but the **commentted code** didn`t work,and the code below works fine

```
let dbclickre = true;
function flipped() {
    if (dbclickre) {
        document.querySelector(".linkrec").setAttribute("Id", "flipped");
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".linkrec").removeAttribute("Id", "flipped")
    }
    dbclickre = !dbclickre;
}
```

- below is the commentted code (I think when i firstly click the last < li > ,js will excute the if statement(and indeed it works fine),but when i click again , the else statement didn't excude(but i have set #flipped .reverse {background: whitesmoke} ) .  why this happening???)

```
// const dbclickre = document.querySelector(".reverse");
// function flipped() {
//     if (dbclickre.style.backgroundColor = 'white') {
//         document.querySelector(".linkrec").setAttribute("Id", "flipped");
//     } else {
//         document.querySelector(".linkrec").removeAttribute("Id", "flipped")
//     }
// }
```

Comment: in your if condition u wrote on = make it two of three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on background color for checking the state of flip, you could check for existence of `Id` attribute. Here the the changed code:

```
const dbclickre = document.querySelector(".reverse");
function flipped() {
    if ( document.querySelector(".linkrec").getAttribute("Id") == undefined ) {
        document.querySelector(".linkrec").setAttribute("Id", "flipped");
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".linkrec").removeAttribute("Id", "flipped")
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

Why `element.style` would not work?

From [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style):

> The `style` property is used to get as well as set the ***inline*** style of an element.

Hence, the `style` property would not work with embedded or external CSS.

Also, it may not be a good idea to use hard-coded colors as the condition, because changing colors in the respective CSS classes would completely break the functionality.

Comment: this works as well,but why background can't do that,or does is means that i shouldn't do it at all(it's a bad way)?